# Error at insert encode password in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, psql, string-literals

i've create this psql table code :

```
CREATE TABLE admin (id INT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO admin (id, username, roles, password) VALUES (nextval('admin_id_seq'), 'admin', '["ROLE_ADMIN"]', '$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$Kcm6sv104bqBtb+FEh+dDQ$caej4aGFAYMvBqKNHgFAGw6+1rua1Iwk/g09mYbOCLMx’);
```

there no single error on my end at terminal but 0 rows on table, any code that i missed ?

Comment: how is this related to symfony? it's unlikely that there is no error (maybe it's hidden in some log file?) if there's no row.

Comment: This is one of the code from symfony fastrack books, unfortunately this code not perfectly documented that's why when i tried with my encode password this error is raise up

Comment: maybe it's just copy-pasta, but the last quote in your query isn't a proper apostrophe.

Comment: may i know where is the error on this query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look closely at your values (truncated below!), you'll see that the very last single quote is actually a "right single quotation mark" (U+2019) and not a "single quote" / "apostrophe" (U+0027), while all other quotes are apostrophe, as they should be.

```
 (nextval('admin_id_seq'), 'admin', '["ROLE_ADMIN"]', '$argon2id$v=19$...’)
                                                                         ^-- this one
```

If you look very closely, you can see that it even looks different. You can zoom in to see the difference more easily.

The solution is to replace the last one with an apostrophe / single quote (U+0027):

```
INSERT INTO admin (id, username, roles, password) VALUES (nextval('admin_id_seq'), 'admin', '["ROLE_ADMIN"]', '$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$Kcm6sv104bqBtb+FEh+dDQ$caej4aGFAYMvBqKNHgFAGw6+1rua1Iwk/g09mYbOCLMx');
```

Comment: wait till you have special characters that can't even be seen ;oD